# Increase value of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

My result should be this:

```
{ "Jane Doe" => 10, "Jim Doe" => 6 }
```

My code looks like this

```
    @user.update_column(:message_count, @message.recipient_username)
```

I get this output for example:

```
"Jane Doe"
```

I don't know how I assign a number to this name for example:

```
{ "Jane Doe" => 1 }
```

and when the same command is returned with the same `recipient_username`, the number should increase:

```
@user.update_column(:message_count, @message.recipient_username)
{ "Jane Doe" => 2 }
```

The last thing I would like to do is that when the `recipient_username` of the message is `"Jim Doe"` and this username is not in the hash, it should be added for example:

```
{ "Jane Doe" => 2, "Jim Doe" => 1 }
```

I read the http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html but i cant transpose it.

Comment: `update_column` updated a column in your database, it's not for updating hashes. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
results = Hash.new { 0 }
DATA.readlines.each do  |line|
  name = line.chomp
  results[name] += 1
end

p results

# >> {"John Doe"=>3, "Jane Doe"=>1, "James Dean"=>1, "Jennifer Smith"=>1, ""=>1}
__END__
John Doe
Jane Doe
John Doe
James Dean
Jennifer Smith
John Doe
```

This generates the new keys with a default value and increments as you go.